# Forcing, symmetry of $\times$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

Let Fn$(\kappa \times \omega,2)$ be a forcing notion.
Then $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$ must hold in $V[G]$ but obviously

$2^{\kappa}$ cannot be $\aleph_0$.

So where is the symmetry of Fn$(\kappa \times \omega,2)$ and Fn$(\omega \times \kappa,2)$ in $V[G]$ lost?

Comment: $V[G]$ satisfies $2^{\aleph_0}=(\lambda^{\aleph_0})^V$ where $\lambda= \max (\aleph_0,\kappa).$

Comment: And the $2^{\aleph_0}$ is in $V$ or in $V[G]$? How did you arrive at that $\max$?

Comment: $V[G]\vDash (2^{\omega}=\mu)$  where $\mu$ is an ordinal and $V\vDash (\mu=\lambda^{\omega})$ where $ \lambda =\max (\omega,\kappa).$... See Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs (1st edition),  by K.Kunen.....Exercises for chapter 7, Exercise section G, Exercise (G1)...(page 246).

Answer (score 3):

There is no symmetry lost, these two forcings are isomorphic and in particular produce the same forcing extensions (one isomorphism arises from the obvious bijection $\omega\times\kappa\rightarrow\kappa\times\omega $ and generally $Fn (X, Y, \lambda)\cong Fn (X', Y, \lambda)$ if there is a bijection $f:X\rightarrow X'$). This forcing adds $\kappa$ many new subsets to $\omega$, but you do not know without further assumptions that $2^\omega=\kappa$ in  $V [G] $  (for example this can never hold if $\kappa=\omega $) you only know for sure that $2^\omega\geq\kappa $ since there still might be a lot of "old" subsets. You observed correctly that you can also think about this forcing as adding $\omega $ many New subsets to $\kappa$ and you get $2^\kappa\geq\aleph_0$ in $V [G] $, which is trivial.

Comment: So how do I prove consistency of CH by forcing with Fn$(\aleph_1 \times \omega,2)$?

Comment: with this forcing you cannot. This forcing only produces a model of CH if the ground model already was a model of CH, to show that CH is relatively consistent with ZFC try the forcing $Fn (\aleph_1, \mathcal {P}(\omega), \aleph_1)$.

Comment: But if the forcing notion is Fn($I,J$),$I,J$ infinite and $G$ is $P$-generic over $M$ then $f=\bigcup G$ and $f$ is a function from $I$ onto $J$. So how does this imply that CH may be proven by forcing notion $Fn(\aleph_1,\cal P(\omega),\aleph_1)$?

Comment: The forcing I gave adds a surjection from $/aleph_1$ onto $\mathcal{P}(\omega)^V $. since it is $\aleph_1$-closed, $\mathcal{P}(\omega)^V= \mathcal{P}(\omega)^{V [G]} $ and this implies CH in $V [G] $

Comment: So why you don't just use $Fn(\aleph_1,\cal P (\omega),\aleph_0)$ instead of $Fn(\aleph_1,\cal P (\omega),\aleph_1)$?

Comment: Because this forcing is not $\aleph_1$-closed and in fact adds new subsets of $/omega$. In any extension of this forcing, the continuum will have size $(2^{2^\omega})^V $ and whether or not this will be $\aleph_1^{V [G]} $ (i.e. CH holds)  acctually depends on whether or not $2^{2^\omega}=(2^\omega)^+$ holds in $V $ (which is false in general).

Comment: Could you please be more specific, how from the exitence of that condition $q$ in $\aleph_1$-closed forcing for countable chains of conditions follows ${\cal P}(\omega)^V={\cal P}(\omega)^{V[G]}$?ANd how this in turn implies it is $\aleph_1^{V[G]}$?

Comment: It is a general fact that if a forcing is $\kappa$ closed and $\alpha <\kappa $ then $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)^V=\mathcal {P}(\alpha)^{V [G]} $, this follows for example from Theorem 15.6 and Lemma 15.8 in Jech Set Theory (Note that what I call $\kappa $- closed is $<\kappa $-closed in Jechs notation). Theorem 15.6 also implies that cardinals $\leq \kappa $ are preserved as otherwise you would have a new function $f:\lambda\rightarrow V $ in $V [G] $. in our example $aleph_1^V $ is preserved and there is aleph surjection $g:\aleph_1\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\omega) $